# Is doctrine Entity validation enough?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, post, doctrine

I have an Entity class which already has constrains:

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
private $X;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $Y;
```

In my controller i'm getting post data from form and using setMethods on entity class:

```
$property = new PropertyEntity();
$property->setX($request->request->get('X'));
$property->setY($request->request->get('Y'));
```

next step - save to db.

Do I need to do additional validation on post data ? I though I need to use validation library but i'm not sure if it will only add unnecessary overhead since "@ORM" is already form type is already doing some validation.
Any general idea how and where to write validation ?(pseudocode is enough)

Comment: There's no validation here.

Comment: What exactly would you like to validate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question!
ORM mapping map the PHP class to the doctrine metadata (Model).
Assert is a mechanism to validate objects received from form (View/Controller).

This means that you can use assert on objects that are not entities or that you cannot use a mapped field in your formType

You can make validation in the annotation of the field. example:

```
/**
* @Assert\NotBlank
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
private $X;
    
/**
* @Assert\NotBlank
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
*/
private $Y;
```

Don't forget to add:
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

More validation constraints are in this link:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html#basic-constraints